# Do we consider strings to have some cross-sectional area or do we assume them to be 1D?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, string, continuum-mechanics

I was trying to derive a relation between the elongation of a string when transverse waves are produced on it and the string's Young's modulus; an expression that would involve the cross-sectional area of the string.

However, in mechanics problems involving pulleys and all, we usually consider strings to have zero cross-sectional area.

So is this assumed for waves on a string as well or not?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the simplest model of transverse waves on a string ignores Young's modulus. The "stiffness" of the string comes from its tension, not from the properties of the material. For that model, the single parameter of "mass per unit length" of the string is relevant, but the separate parameters "cross section area" and density per unit volume" which you might use to calculate the mass per unit length are not.

However for a more accurate model (especially of "strings" made from metal wire) you need to add the elastic stiffness of the string bending like a beam. In that case the *shape* of the cross section (not just its area) and Young's modulus do matter.

At the other extreme, a stiff "string" could be modeled just as a flexible beam, ignoring any axial tension completely.

All three options are standard models that you can find in textbooks or on the web.

Comment: So for the 'simplest model', does it mean that there is no hindrance or potential energy associated with the elongation of the string?

Comment: Kind of like a spring with spring constant tending to zero?

Comment: Typically strings are assumed to be inextensible